# Dynamic background Image with Opacity

Tags: jquery, css

I need to set up an area with a background image which will be "dynamically set" using an offsite SOA server call.  So, I have no idea what the width or height of the images will be (they literally can be any dimensions) and I don't even know what the url will be until run time.  I need the background image to scale to take up the width of display responsively but have opacity such that text will sit on top of that image.

1. I've taken a look at this: 
   https://scotch.io/quick-tips/how-to-change-a-css-background-images-opacity

This solution partially works but it as well as the rest of the answers I've found on this all seem to assume the image url is known and/or can be "hardwired" into the css file.  I found another solution that uses JQuery to modify the background URL but they don't seem to work together.  Is there a recommended way to do this?

Obviously, I could make JQuery write ALL the CSS but that doesn't seem like a great way to do it.  It doesn't make sense that CSS files have url's hardwired in them in the first place since dynamic images is a more practical thing that happens in real life in a real web application.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.restHeaderBack').each(function(){
    var getImg = $(this).attr('data-img');
    $(this).css('background-image', 'url(' getImg + ')');
  });
});
```

```css
.restHeaderBack:before {
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 3em;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0.2;
  /*
  background-image: url("../Artwork/Example/CypressG_.JPG");
  */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 0;
  -ms-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="restHeaderBack" data-img="../Artwork/Example/CypressG_.JPG">
  <h2 class="nobr">Cypress Grill</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand why do you need jQuery to edit a CSS rule while you have the URL already which you can either place it directly on the element with Style attribute, or create an img tag as well.

Comment: Well I might be over thinking it.  However, if I use style, like this-->
<div class="restHeaderBack" style="background-image: url(../Artwork/Example/CypressG_.JPG)">

to set the url, then the image shows up but it ignores the css class.

Comment: Yes and as I understood that is the idea to set a background image independently on each element rather than using a single CSS selector to set the same background for all matches. Check out the CSS Hierarchy http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Comment: The problem you are facing is that you want to set your background-image dynamically on your pseudo-element (which you can't), right?

Comment: Well that's in a nutshell where I find myself based on attempting to do what I set out to do.  [ I need a background image with opacity, that is responsive, that scales, with text on top and the url image will be determined dynamically at run time from one page display to the next.  So the styling is always the same, the url is dynamic ]

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by using option 1.  Not as snazzy and not as perfect but seems to be working sufficiently.

```
<div class="restHeaderBack" >
    <h2 class="nobr">Cypress Grill</h2>
    <img src="../Artwork/Example/CypressG_.JPG">
</div>


.restHeaderBack {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100px;
    border-bottom: 1px gray solid;
}
.restHeaderBack h2 {
    padding: 5px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    font-weight:900;
} 

}
.restHeaderBack img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    opacity: 0.2;   
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to fix your javascript code, here is a possible solution.

[As I don't have the image you are trying to display, I used a test image for the demo]

```js
var divObj = $('.restHeaderBack');
var imageUrl = divObj.data('img');
divObj.css('background-image', 'url(' + imageUrl + ')');
```

```css
.restHeaderBack {
content: ' ';
display: block;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 3em;
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
z-index: 1;
opacity: 0.2;
/*
background-image: url("../Artwork/Example/CypressG_.JPG");*/
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 50% 0;
-ms-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="restHeaderBack" data-img="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTUHWYIxS_pF_qVRkUox4kwlHVCok05IK30-2RZIt7ha8iZFCAF8g">
    <h2 class="nobr">Cypress Grill</h2>
  </div>
```

UPATE:
are you looking for something like this? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PqGzmb

Comment: When I run this and view it, there is no opacity and there is no scaling either on the image. Its just repeating an image with no opacity and I can't even see the text because its black. So it is ignoring the css :before

Comment: In my code, I was correcting your javascript code only. The image is repeating because of your css code. Can you share your image?

Comment: The image makes no difference.  You can use any image.  After all, I will have no idea about the size or url of the image is either.  Your image is fine except that it has no opacity.  Here is a codepen with your code.  Remove the JQuery/JavaScript to see how it "should" works with your "hardwired" background url.  Now, add the comment code back to the css file and put the jquery code back and you see your image without opacity and sizing.  
http://codepen.io/codeaholic/pen/pJEyGw

Comment: The background image is suppose to be a "flavor", "glimpse", or "flare" of the company.  Unforked http://codepen.io/codeaholic/pen/pJEyGw and forked codepen:  http://codepen.io/codeaholic/pen/JdRXze

Comment: Also, I did not downvote this...it was someone else.